# Angular - two states : 2 load perfectly fine and the 3rd doesnt -Why?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have 3 angular states with controllers etc and 2 load fine while the third just doesnt. Besides that the 3rd one has a different name of course, they are identical and avter an hour almost starring at my code I just dont know what to do here. Any ideas would be great!
For the main state I keep getting: Error: Could not resolve 'main' from state ''
WORKS:

js/auth/auth.js

```
          app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
              $stateProvider.state('auth', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/js/auth/auth.html',
                controller: 'authCtrl'
              });
            });
```

js/auth/auth.controller.js

```
            app.controller('authCtrl', function($scope){
            console.log("whyyyy")
            })
```

2nd state which works too:

js/test/test.js

```
          app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
              $stateProvider.state('test', {
                url: '/test',
                templateUrl: '/js/test/test.html',
                controller: 'testCtrl'
              });
            });
```

js/test/test.controller.js

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
  console.log("test")
})
```

now the 3rd is identical but doesnt load:

js/main/main.js

```
          app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
              $stateProvider.state('main', {
                url: '/main',
                templateUrl: '/js/main/main.html',
                controller: 'mainCtrl'
              });
            });
```

js/main/main.controller.js

```
         app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
            console.log("home")

            })
```

index.html:

```
   <script src="app.js"></script>
   <script src="js/auth/auth.js"></script>
   <script src="js/auth/auth.controller.js"></script>

   <script src="js/test/test.js"></script>
   <script src="js/test/test.controller.js"></script>

   <script src="js/main/main.js"></script>
   <script src="js/main/main.controller.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myTesting">
<ul>
  <li ui-sref="test">test</li>
  <li ui-sref="main">home</li>
</ul>
<ui-view></ui-view>

</body>
```

I use node but it cant have anything to do with any routes or anything from the server side because 2 of the 3 states load perfectly fine.

Comment: A note on style, `controller`s should always be _declared_ with PascalCase names and not camelCase names. Also, there is no need to register your controllers with `module.controller` as you can specify the actual controller definition as the state config object's `controller` property.

Comment: Are these part of the same module? If not, if the 3rd one is in a different module, did you load that one in the main module?

Comment: They shouldnt be. I load all three in index.hmtl, then all of them are seperate folders: js/main..js/test..js/auth